# How to change horizontal excel data to a table format

Tags: python

I want to manipulate excel data by using Python, Please help me...

Excel data looks like:

```
Script_name     Homepage    Signinlink  signin
 SC-001           1              1        1
 SC-002           1              1        0
```

Expected result:

```
Transaction_Name    Count
SC-001_Homepage       1
SC-001_Signinlink     1
SC-001_signin         1
SC-002_Homepage       1
SC-002_Signinlink     1
SC-002_signin         0
```

I am concatenating the each script number with transaction name and under count column i am displaying the count of each transaction. I am using Xlrd to read the excels. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you will get Transaction?

Comment: Transaction name is available in Excel

Comment: Question is not clear, attach screenshot of Excel File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your query, below script may help.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# data =  {'Script_name':['SC-001', 'SC-002'], 'Homepage': [1, 1] , 'Signinlink': [1, 1], 'signin': [1, 0]}
# data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())

# To read excel file
data = pd.read_excel(r"Excel File Path", sheet_name='Name of Sheet which contains data', dtype=object)

df = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['Script_name'], value_name='Count')
df['Transaction_Name'] = df['Script_name'] + '_' + df['variable']

print(df)

  Script_name    variable  Count   Transaction_Name
0      SC-001    Homepage      1    SC-001_Homepage
1      SC-002    Homepage      1    SC-002_Homepage
2      SC-001  Signinlink      1  SC-001_Signinlink
3      SC-002  Signinlink      1  SC-002_Signinlink
4      SC-001      signin      1      SC-001_signin
5      SC-002      signin      0      SC-002_signin

Final_df = df[['Transaction_Name', 'Count']]
print(Final_df)

Final_df.to_csv(r'Destination Path', index=False)
```

Import & Compare:-

```
# Sample DS Created:

df1 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink'], 'Count': [1, 1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=df1.keys())

df2 =  {'Transaction_Name':['SC-001_Homepage', 'SC-002_Homepage', 'SC-001_Signinlink'], 'Count': [2, 1, 2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=df2.keys())

'''
# You can import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"First CSV File Path", dtype=object)
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"Second CSV File Path", dtype=object)

'''

print('\n', df1)
print('\n',df2)

df1['Compare'] = df1['Transaction_Name'] + df1['Count'].astype(str)
df2['Compare'] = df2['Transaction_Name'] + df2['Count'].astype(str)

print('\n', df1.loc[~df1['Compare'].isin(df2['Compare'])])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help SPy, i will implement and let you know if i need any further help to achieve this.

Comment: Hi SPy the data which i provided to you is sample data. Actual data will have 15 script names like SC-001, SC-002.....SC-015 and 46 transaction names and count also will be there as mentioned before. So for this many scripts and transactions  declaring the data as shown in your answer is difficult. Can you please suggest me if there is another method to resolve this?

Comment: @Swetha Gorantla, "declaring the data" I have given just example, you can load excel data using pd.read_excel to dataframe "data". Otherwise I can not generate results right? First two lines you can exclude. Is last two lines script meets your requirements?

Comment: HI Spy, I implemented the above code and able to get the desired output. Thanks for the help. But i am unable to get how to declare all my excel data by using pd.read_excel to dataframe "data". If possible can you please give me the steps.

Comment: @Swetha Gorantla, Let me know about your files. Like How Many files, File type, Is that same structure, then I can help you

Comment: I have one excel file and it is XLSX type in the same structure given above. Data looks like below
                Homepge        Signin          Search             Addtobasket
SC001          1                    1                    1                          0
SC002           1                    0                    1                          2
SC003           0                     1                     1                         1
...
....
....
......

Comment: @Swetha Gorantla, data = pd.read_excel(r"Excel File Path", sheet_name='Name of Sheet which contains data', dtype=object)

Comment: Thanks SPy. This worked and expected results are coming. Now as a next step can you please help me how to get only column 3 and 4 from results? And wanted to rearrange as 4th column should be as 1st column and 3rd column should be as 2nd column.

Comment: @SwethaGorantla, Added 2 lines.

Comment: How to remove serial number column from the result. I mean first column which is 1,2,3....

Comment: @SwethaGorantla, while exporting you can mute it, updated script check.

Comment: Got it SPy. I could implement it. Thanks a lot for your prompt responses.

Comment: Now i got the data "Transaction_Name" and "Count" into a csv file. I have same type of with "Transaction_Name" and "Count" in another csv file but count is different. Can you please let me know how to compare both files and check for which Transaction_Name the count is different?

Comment: Also Spy, when i am reading the csv file which we save by using the above code i am getting below error.
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'Transact'
And code i used is as below...
df_OLD = pd.read_excel(r"WLM.csv", sheet_name='WLM', dtype=object)

Comment: @SwethaGorantla, Updated pls check.

Comment: When implemented i am getting below error
    print('\n', df1.loc[~df1['Compare'].isin(df2['Compare'])])
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: It is cleared, I updated the code incorrectly. Now i updated correctly.

Comment: Wanted to get the output in a csv file. While comparing the both files i need the result like as below...
1) Count difference in both CSV for Transactions
2) For example in first CSV there will be 100 transactions. Out of 100 only 80 transactions are there in the second CSV. Will i be able to see what are those 20 transactions missing in second CSV.
3) For example in First CSV there are 100 transactions but in the second CSV there will be 110 transactions. Will I be able to see what are those 20 extra transactions.
Thanks in advance